# The Do's and Don'ts of currency calculations in Apex

Tags: apex, bestpractice, multi-currency, decimal, rounding

Ok, I am not a math expert, but I know about the basics of rounding problematics in programming languages.

In one of my apps, I do some quite complex (math-wise and infrastructure -wise) currency calculations, e.g.:

- Using SUM() on Decimal fields in AggregateResult SOQL query on million of records
- Applying Exchange Rates to those values in Apex using regular * Math
- Doing basic math (+-*/) with high value Decimals (billions of dollars)

In my small-number test everything is working fine, but when I let my code run on billion of USD amounts I see some big rounding errors. As the calculations are somewhat complex I first post this question before I dig into analysis.

**Are there Do's and Don't when it comes to currency math in Apex?**

Sorry for not providing more details here, but I was unable to extract the important parts without exposing tom much.

**Especially reading [this blog post from Appirio](http://techblog.appirio.com/2012/11/salesforce-and-decimal-places.html) left me with bad feelings ;)**

Comment: What makes you feel so confident that the errors are due to rounding, and not some logical problem?

Comment: Actually its not really proven, but the fact that no errors appear in Unit tests with small numbers but in real life scenarios..but you're right.

Comment: Also reading this: http://techblog.appirio.com/2012/11/salesforce-and-decimal-places.html made me a little bit nervous ;)

Answer (score 7):

Don't use [Double](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_double.htm) because of the loss of precision due to the floating point representation.  Do use [Decimal](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm).  If you're familiar with Java the Decimal class in Apex is the equivalent of the BigDecimal.

Write lots of good unit tests.